# Delay loop in javascript function

Tags: javascript, axios

I have multiple API calls that I'm using to delete user data for automated tests.

First I get an access token

```
    async function getAccessToken(email, pwd) {
    try {
        const form = {email: email, password: pwd};
        let config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            }
        };
        const accessToken = await axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/test/token`, qs.stringify(form), config);
        console.log(accessToken.data.data.accessToken);
        return accessToken.data.data.accessToken
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(``+email+` produced the Error = ` + e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I then use that token to delete the data needed

```
 async function TMDeleteAllGoals (emailAddress) {
    try {
        var accessToken = await setup.getAccessToken(emailAddress, 'Test4321');
        var userId = await user.getUserId(emailAddress);
        var goalids = await getAllTMGoalID(emailAddress);
        console.log(`Deleting all goals for ` + emailAddress + ``);
        for (const goalid of goalids) {
            const response = await axios.delete(`${process.env.TM_API_URL}/test/users/`+userId+`/goals/`+goalids+``, {'headers': {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken + ''}});
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(``+emailAddress+` produced the Error = ` + e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I then need to run this for 1000 different users, so I execute using a loop

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 1001; i++) {
    //console.log(i);
    deleteGoals.TMDeleteAllGoals(`loadtest${i}@test.com`);
}
```

The problem I am having is that here appears to be a max for concurrent calls to get my access token (not sure what the limit is yet). So if I hit it with too many users, it will start to return null instead of the token.

Is there a way I can put a timeout in between each call in the loop, to try and slow it down. I have tried this, but it doesn't execute anything.

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function deleteTheGoals () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 1001; i++) {
        //console.log(i);
        await timeout(500);
        const deleteGoals = await deleteGoals.TMDeleteAllGoals(`loadtest${i}@test.com`);
    }
}
```

Comment: when accepted answer, you can upvote too ehehhehehehehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a max request config in your server, so even if you do a timeout it doesn't guarantee that the request will end before 500 milliseconds.
Why not send them one after another ?

```
async function arraysWithAllIndexes(array) {
  for(const i of array) {
    await deleteGoals.TMDeleteAllGoals(`loadtest${i}@test.com`);
  }
};
```